# Importing map information with osm2pgrouting?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, osm2po, osm2pgrouting

I'm importing the cartography of Spain with osm2pgrouting.

I want to import address information, that is, the tag addr = *.
I modified the file mapconfig.xml follows:

```
  <type name="junction" id="4">
    <class name="roundabout" id="401" />
  </type>  
  <type name="addr:housenumber" id="5"></type>
  <type name="addr:street" id="6"></type>
  <type name="addr:flats" id="7"></type>
  <type name="addr:city" id="8"></type>
  <type name="addr:country" id="9"></type>
</configuration>
```

I did not get any result.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [osm2psql](http://learnosm.org/en/osm-data/osm2pgsql/) for example, if you want to import data, that is not (road) network data.

osm2pgrouting only handles linestring geometries and will not work with point data.